# Tensorboard "compute time" incorrectly summed up

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensorboard shows incorrect compute time for a group of nodes vs their sum individually. Is this is a bug or do I need to interpret it differently?

Time as a group is ~10 seconds.
[image: Group Time]

Each individual op need roughly 40~50 micro seconds (6 * 50 microseconds << 10 seconds!)
[image: Individual]

As you can see the individual operations come up to much less than 1 second, yet the group time is 10 seconds!

Comment: I am having the same issue as you. I think it's more a problem of misinterpreting the overall compute time for a node, rather than the "summation" being incorrect. As a matter of fact I think tensorboard is not doing a summation, but probably something else, mainly because some operations can be parallelized.